# how to show SVG with Django objects?

Tags: python, django, svg

I'm having an issue with Django objects, whenever I show my svg file on my template it is not shown as image but tags. So my question is how can I show SVG image through the template ?

**template.html**

```
{% for icon in icons %}
     <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 208.000000 300.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
         {{ icon.icons }}
     </svg>
{% endfor %}
```

**one of `icon.icons` data :**

```
<g transform="translate(0.000000,300.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#161616" stroke="none">
<path class="node" id="node1" d="M1523 2911 c-30  ..."></path>
</g>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,300.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="none">
</g>
```

I use `TextField` to contain this data. I think the data is as "string" so I was wondering how to show it as SVG on my web page ?

Comment: Updated my answer because I generated your problem and was able to understand exactly what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) template filter, like this:

```
{{ icon.icons|safe }}
```

**[UPDATE]**: I tried your problem and indeed the `TextField` is rendered with double quotes (`"<g>...</g>"`). I tried to strip them off but no luck. Then I thought, why not just use the excellent [`django-ckeditor`](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor) package. If so, then you can declare your "rich" model fields like this:

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class MyIcon(models.Model):

    icon = RichTextField('Text', help_text='Now text will be stored as a rich text field!')
```

Then, in your templates render it like this:

```
<!-- template.html -->

{% for icon in icons %}
    <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100px" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 208.000000 300.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
         {{ icon.icon|safe }}
     </svg>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I thought about using Ckeditor but I was also searching for a way without it :) I guess I'll have to use it like this

Comment: Until Django implement their own rich field use ckeditor. Glad I could help!